# Using maths on variables when adding item to an array in Velocity

Tags: arrays, velocity

I am sure this is simple but i can't figure out the correct syntax to this, I have tried various places for "" , '' and (), and looking it up but not sure what to search for.

I want to evaluate the following and add an array to an existing array

```
$subnets.add(["Infra_IOT", 600, "$oct1.$oct2." + ($oct3 + 1) + ".65", "255.255.255.128"])
```

So if we assume

$oct1 = 10, $oct2=20 and $oct3 = 30

I want to be able to call $subnets[0][2] and get the result "10.20.31.65"

but whatever i try i can get it to work and i can't find any documentation on how to format this line correctly. Would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: What language and framework is this? Please [edit] post and add appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a templatized string.

But you must do the calculation beforehand, and also store the result if `add()` somewhere otherwise it will be displayed (`List.add()` returns `true`).

```
#set($inc3 = $oct3 + 1)
#set($junk = $subnets.add(["Infra_IOT", 600, "$oct1.$oct2.$inc.65", "255.255.255.128"]))
$subnets[0][2]
```